# Iterating through javascript array using ranged for loop

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC app where the controller takes a list of objects, serializes it using `JavaScriptSerializer()` creating a JSON object that is passed to the client side view.

For some reason, when I try to iterate through the object using a ranged for loop, each object is undefined, but when I iterate through the object with a regular for loop and index the object using the current iteration value in square brackets, I'm able to access each sub object (i.e. this works `for(var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++)` vs this `for(var sub in jsonObj)`. **Why doesn't the ranged for loop work in this instance?**

JSON Object:

```
[
    "Obj1": {
            "Value1": "3454234",
            "Value2": "345643564",
            "Value3": "665445",
            "Value4": "True"
        },
        "Obj2": {
            "Value1": "3454234",
            "Value2": "345643564",
            "Value3": "665445",
            "Value4": "True"
        },
        "Obj3": {
            "Value1": "3454234",
            "Value2": "345643564",
            "Value3": "665445",
            "Value4": "True"
        }
]
```

## EDIT

```
for(var sub in finalJson){
  console.log(sub["Value1"])
}
```

Comment: try `for(var sub of jsonObj)`  the `in` isn't doing what you expect -> `A different property name is assigned to variable on each iteration.`  So the property name for the first element is `0` as that's what arrays are.

Comment: @Keith refer back to the OP please.

Comment: Please show us what you tried.

Comment: How are you calling each jsonObj in the for loop?

Comment: @loremIpsum1771 Pardon?

Comment: @shawon191 just updated the post

Comment: @CliveCiappara just added the for loop to the post

Comment: @Keith Sorry, I misread your comment. I didn't notice that you had an of instead of an in. Your version works. Why doesn't the in work here as it does in other languages like python?

Comment: The `in` is just giving you property names,. so a property name for an array item is `0,1,2,3` etc.  So to work with `in` instead of `of`.. do `finalJson[sub].Value1`.

Comment: is this es6? Because the of keyword is causing an intellisense error in visual studio even though it works in jsfiddle.

Comment: It's 2015, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of  Most browsers should support,..

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not valid, you either need to remove the object names so it's a valid list:

```
[{
   "Value1": "3454234",
   "Value2": "345643564",
   "Value3": "665445",
   "Value4": "True"
 }, {
   "Value1": "3454234",
   "Value2": "345643564",
   "Value3": "665445",
   "Value4": "True"
 } {
   "Value1": "3454234",
   "Value2": "345643564",
   "Value3": "665445",
   "Value4": "True"
 }]
```

in which case a ranged loop will work:

```
JsonObj.forEach(function(obj) {
   console.log(obj);
})
```

or convert it to an object containing the other objects as properties:

```
{
  "Obj1": {
    "Value1": "3454234",
    "Value2": "345643564",
    "Value3": "665445",
    "Value4": "True"
  },
  "Obj2": {
    "Value1": "3454234",
    "Value2": "345643564",
    "Value3": "665445",
    "Value4": "True"
  },
  "Obj3": {
    "Value1": "3454234",
    "Value2": "345643564",
    "Value3": "665445",
    "Value4": "True"
  }
}
```

in which case you can loop through via the keys:

```
for(var key in JsonObj) {
   console.log(key);
}
```

The reason your second loop wasn't working is because `for..in` is used to iterate through an objects keys, but your JSON is an array of objects, not an object

Answer (score 0):

The JSON Object you've provide is not correct JSON object. It is an array of key-value pairs. Correct JSON object must be surrounded by { ... }, not by [ ... ]. You can check variable type `jsonObj instanceof Array;` If it gets `true` - then that is the reason.